# CPAP refresh purchase

Tags: sleep-apnea, brands

My CPAP is hitting the 5 year mark, so it is time to buy a new one, before the current one fails.  That being said, I am considering purchasing the same Resmed S9 model because having two of the same model enables compatibility of accessories.  There is a newer S10 model.  Has anyone made a the decision to stay with an older model for this reason: if you did, do you believe it was the better decision?